# Intersection of 2 planes - find vector of intersection

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I was trying to figure out the curve of intersection of these 
2 planes:
$$3x - y + z = 4 $$
$$ y + z = 2.$$

I realize it will be a straight and not curved, and feel like I should be able to do the math but I just can't arrive at the posted answer.  I was confused how they parametrized this and would just like to see the work so I can have an ah-ha moment. 
correct answer is :

$$C(t)= \,\langle 2t, -1+3t, 3-3t\rangle$$ $t $ includes all real numbers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One way is to recognize that the intersection must satisfy the equation for both planes, and must therefore satisfy their sum:

$$
(3x-y+z)+(y+z) = 4+2
$$

$$
3x+2z = 6
$$

You can then let $x = t$, and then $3t+2z = 6$, whence we get $z = 3-\frac{3}{2}t$.  You can then rewrite your first equation as

$$
y = 3x+z-4
$$

to obtain an expression for $y$ in terms of $t$.  Well, that is more or less what the solution did, except that they chose to set $x = 2t$, in order to avoid some unsightly fractions.  Otherwise, the parametrization is the same.

Comment: oh I see, it was 2t to keep everything a whole number.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We know that the two planes hit at an intersection, and thus their
intersection should be orthogonal to the "facing" of said planes. Hence,
you can find the (orthogonal) vector of intersection by taking the
cross product the two normal vectors of these planes, since the cross
product of two vectors produces a vector that is perpendicular to
both of the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Putting $x=0$ and solving the two equations we obtain a point which satisfies both equations i.e.$(0,-1,3)$.

Therefore this point would lie on the line of intersection of the two planes. Let equation of line be 
$$ \frac{x-0}{l}=\frac{y+1}{m}=\frac{z-3}{n}$$.

Angle between this line and both the planes will be $0$.

Therefore,

$3l-m+n=0$

$m+n=0$

Solving we get$\displaystyle \frac{l}{2}=\frac{m}{3}\frac{n}{-3}$.

Thus equation of line will be $\displaystyle \frac{x-0}{2}=\frac{y+1}{3}=\frac{z-3}{-3}=t(say)$.

Thus $x=2t,y=3t-1,3-3t$